# Use protobuf on android to send data to WCF Service (using protobuf.net)

Tags: android, .net, wcf, blob, protocol-buffers

I need to send a object containing 256kb to 18Mb of data from an android device to a WCF service.
I just found out about protobuf.net and agree this is the way to go.
Most examples I find showing use of protobuf on android are designed to make queries like:

> www.webservice.com/API/MaxItems=10. 
>   What I need is a way to sent entire BLOBs to my webservice, not just parameters.
>   Can anyone point me in the right direction for coding this using android 2.3.3 and WCF.Net?

My scenario is as follows:

Webservice is serving clients using .Net and Silverlight and also clients on the android platform.
Webservice will serve data from filesystem and SQL to clients using protobuf.
Data beeing served will contain basic types and smaller binary chunks. 4-50Kb as protobuf objects. 
There will be 17 functions taking parameters of basic types and 6 functions taking protobuf objects as parameters. One of the functions will take a protobuf object having 4 byte[] summing up to a maximum of 18Mb.

The characteristics of the served data makes protobuf a perfect match.

One of the requirements on the WebService API is to hold all these functions in one interface.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think your best bet *in that scenario* (with android etc) would be to use regular in-memory serialization to create a BLOB, and then use whatever tools are available (http-post, WSE, sockets, whatever) to send that BLOB, and deserialize at the other end. Getting WCF to own the serialize/deserialize is a huge pain, especially if you aren't using full .NET. This approach should also make it pretty easy to switch between transport types entirely if needed, as you aren't really asking WCF to do much.

Comment: Ok i get the pain part :) I need to elaborate more to make my case clear. Please see my updated question.